# Como recuperar el valor de un input?

Tags: angular, protractor

Estoy intentando hacer un test case muy simple escribir en un input y leer el valor de este usando Angular y Protractor. Pero no puedo recuperar este valor, me retorna un **null**.

Precondiciones:

1. Crear proyecto en blanco con angular-cli
2. Crear un formulario reactivo con un solo input

   app.component.html

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="form">
       <input id="input-email" name="input-email" type="text" formControlName="email" />
   </form>
   ```

   app.component.ts

   ```
   form: FormGroup;

   constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    email:  ''
    });
   }
   ```

   protractor.conf.ts (como viene por defecto al crear el proyecto con angular-cli)

   ```
   const { SpecReporter, StacktraceOption } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

   /**
    * @type { import("protractor").Config }
    */
   exports.config = {
     allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
     specs: ['./src/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'],
     capabilities: {    browserName: 'chrome' },
     directConnect: true,
     SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
     baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',
     framework: 'jasmine',
     jasmineNodeOpts: {
     showColors: true,
     defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,
     print: function() {}
      },
     onPrepare() {
      require('ts-node').register({
      project: require('path').join(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')
      });
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({
       spec: {
       displayStacktrace: StacktraceOption.PRETTY
     }
    }));
   }
   };
   ```

   app.po.ts

   ```
   import { browser, by, element } from 'protractor';

   export class AppPage {

      async navigateTo(): Promise<unknown> {
         return browser.get(browser.baseUrl);
      }
   }
   ```

   app.e2e-spec.ts

   ```
   import { AppPage } from './app.po';
   import { browser, by, element, ElementFinder, logging } from 'protractor';

   describe('workspace-project App', () => {
      let page: AppPage;

      beforeEach(async () => {
        page = new AppPage();
      });

      it('test case 1', async () => {
        await page.navigateTo();
        const el: ElementFinder = element(by.name('input-email'));
        await el.sendKeys('12345');
        expect(await el.getAttribute('value')).toEqual('abc');
      });

      afterEach(async () => {
        // Assert that there are no errors emitted from the browser
        const logs = await browser.manage().logs().get(logging.Type.BROWSER);
        expect(logs).not.toContain(
          jasmine.objectContaining({
            level: logging.Level.SEVERE,
          } as logging.Entry)
        );
      });
    });
   ```

terminal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado, usar otros localizadores, usando el flujo de control, usando

```
await browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
```

Y siempre me retorna null.

Alguien puede ayudarme? Gracias

Comment: ¿Has tratado de depurar el código? prueba a añadir `debugger;` justo antes de buscar el elemento, quizá la página está cargada pero Angular aún no ha generado el HTML con el input.

Comment: No he probado hacer un debugger pero si se que se escribe el valor del input, visualmente se puede observar, lo que quiere decir que el elemento existe, se encuentra renderizado, pero al recuperar su valor retorna null.